# Real-Time, App-Based Tool Tracking and Inventory Management System

Tags: sensors, precise-positioning

For one of my classes, I need to create a sensor system that can connect with an app that will be able to track when specific tools leave a certain area. I do not know which sensor to implement that will connect to an app. I have been looking into different proximity or position sensors but I do not know which one to use. Does anybody have any starting points for me?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Payton Aussin, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: just pick a sensor at random from a group of potential candidates, then evaluate its suitability ... right now your post is `I have to track unknown objects in an unknown environment. what should I do?`